# Input text no longer editable when using register with react-hook-form

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to set up react-fook-form to validate my forms, but when I use the register function on a text input (in my case the username input), this input is no longer editable, I can't type anything inside.

```
const {register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }} = useForm();
const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
.....

  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <label htmlFor="username">Username : </label>
            <input type="text" value={username}
              onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}
             {...register('username', { required: 'Please, type in your username' })}
                    />
            {errors.username && <span style={{color: 'red'}}><br/>{errors.username.message}</span>}
             <br/>
             <label htmlFor="password">Password : </label>
             <input type="password" value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
             <br/>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally found the solution myself.

Since the version 7 of react-hook-form library, we have to place "onChange" inside the register function like so :

```
<input type="text" value={username} {...register('username', {
    required: 'Please, type in your username',
    onChange: e => setUsername(e.target.value)
    })}/>
```

Comment: no, it's not true, you are setting the `value` attribute on input. if you want to controll input's value  you can use `Controller` otherwise you don't need to set `onChange` and `value` attributes.